# Does whereEqualTo support HashMap equality?

Tags: android, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore, hashmap, equality

The [`whereEqualTo`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/kotlin/com/google/firebase/firestore/Query#whereequalto) API can take `Any` as its argument. Does this mean that I can pass it a `HashMap<K, V>` and it will compare its matching fields with that of a field of `map` type in the `Firestore` database or do I have to manually compare each property of the map?

I've build a query like this one

```
collection.whereEqualTo("meta", hashMapOf( // <-- using full hash-map for matching
    "user" to "JD",
    "name" to "John"
))
```

where `meta` is a `map`-type field with two key/value pairs.

The document I'm trying to match has this structure:

```
{
    "createdOn": as timestamp
    ...other properties
    "meta": as map
    {
        "user": "JD", as string
        "name": "John" as string
    }
}
```

The criteria I use should yield some results but it doesn't (without crashing) so I was wondering whether I made a mistake somewhere else or is this type of a query simply not supported? The result is empty.

I might also be searching only for the `name` property with a simpler query like this one to find all *Johns*

```
collection.whereEqualTo("meta", hashMapOf( // <-- using parcial hash-map for matching

    "name" to "John"
))
```

Will it match only `name` fields or does it require a full-map?

I mean, should the previous query work or do I need to rewrite as this?

```
collection
    .whereEqualTo("meta.user", "JD")
    .whereEqualto("meta.name", "John")
```

Comment: Please edit the question to show the document that you think this query should match.  Also be clear about what `user` and `name` are.  Hard coding the values works best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firestore can compare items of a map in your client code with a map in a document. But the maps must be completely equivalent, so you must specify all properties in your code. So something like this should work:

```
collection.whereEqualTo("meta", hashMapOf( // <-- using parcial hash-map for matching
    "user" to "JD",
    "name" to "John"
))
```

If you can't get this to work, edit your question to include a screenshot of the document you think this should match and I'll have another look.

There is no way specify partial map matches for a field, so if that's what you need, you'll indeed need to add separate conditions for each nested field.

Comment: Indeed, I created more tests and partial maps don't work. You need to compare each field separately and you need to create multiple indexes to support all possible combinations.